# Bootstrap 4 Grid issue in small devices

Tags: flexbox, bootstrap-4

My code is given below

```
<div class="row align-items-center">
  <div class="col-12 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    One of three columns
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
   One of three columns
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS look like below

```
.row {
    height: calc(70vh - 60px);
}
```

When I check-in mobile or small device grid item put some space in upper side and lower side. screenshot attached below 
[image]

you can see space. I want to make div without space.
How can I?

Comment: change the row height to auto, you'll be done

Comment: what do you want? you want space up and down side and place the both divs center of the row, right?

Comment: @WasiF I want to remove space and place both div in verticle center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div style="height: 200px;background-color: sandybrown;" class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="row no-gutters d-flex bg-primary">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 bg-info">on small 12-cols and medium or above 6-cols</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 bg-warning">on small 12-cols and medium or above 6-cols</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

if you want no padding, no margin only on small screen, you can use `media query` in `scss`

```
@media (max-width: 576px) { 
      margin: 0px; padding: 0px 
}
```

Comment: is there any way to apply no-gutters class only in small devices? like hidden-xs

Comment: are you using css or scss?

Comment: i used css in my project

Comment: if it helped you, I am pleased to hear that.